# Convergence to function that is not measurable

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, measure-theory

> Suppose ($X,\cal M, \mu$) is not complete. Show that there is a sequence {$f_n$} of measurable functions on $X$ that converges pointwise a.e. on $X$ to a function $f$ that is not measurable.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Pick a non-measurable subset $E$ of a null set, and let $f_n=0$ for all $n$. Then $f_n\to\chi_E$ a.e.

Comment: Harald, thank you for your response.

So, since I'm showing that there exists a sequence that satisfies these conditions, I can just pick any non-measurable E. For showing purposes, should I actually pick a specific set? Or just say "non-measurable"?

Comment: You can't pick a specific set, because you don't know one. The hypothesis of non-completeness only guarantees the *existence* of one, it does not tell you how to specify one. So just say “non-measurable”.

Comment: I guess you mean a non-measurable subset of a null set. A null set must be measurable.

Comment: @Hua I had in mind the following definition: A *null set* is a subset of a measurable set whose measure is zero. I think this is (a least slightly) better than assuming *a priori* that null sets are measurable. With this definition, a measure is complete iff all null sets are indeed measurable, for example. It is possible, though, that this convention is not universally followed, so I'll let your edit stand, in order to avoid the ambiguity.