# measure theory question about complete measure spaces

Tags: measure-theory

suppose that (X,M,\mu) is a measure space that is not complete. Show that there is a sequence of measurable functions on X that converge to a function that is not measurable.

I'm lost here!! is giving an example is enough or I need to show the question in general? if there is a proof I'd like some comments and/or hints. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Converge how? Pointwise? This is an important detail!

Comment: This is already answered in [here][1]


  [1]: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/330605/convergence-to-function-that-is-not-measurable